# Как сделать правильный цикл в After effects. Использующий JavaScript

Tags: javascript, циклы, after-effects

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Я попытался сделать цикл, который будет отнимать от числа "a" другое число, каждые 9 кадров, пока стартовое число не станет равно 0 и выводить число на экран. Но AE19 просто зависает, каждый раз.

```
a = 100;
b = timeToFrames(t = time + thisComp.displayStartTime, fps = 1.0 / thisComp.frameDuration, isDuration = false) //отсюда берётся текущий проигрываемый кадр композиции.
while (a > 0){ 
  if (b%9==0){
  a -= 10;
}
}
```

Как должен выглядеть правильный код?

```
a = 100;
b = timeToFrames(t = time + thisComp.displayStartTime, fps = 1.0 / thisComp.frameDuration, isDuration = false) 
if (a > 0){ 
  if (b%9==0){
  a -= 10;
}
}
```

Через if

Comment: А почему он не должен зависать, если вы из цикла никогда не выйдете, потому как число `а` не меняется и всегда больше нуля.

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы переменная перезаписывалась?

Comment: Переменная i в цикле - это была опечатка. И с правильной переменной "a" программа всё равно зависает.

Comment: Не нужен тут цикл, сделайте еще один if на проверку a > 0. У вас получается, что если 'b' не удовлетворяет условию, то всё - 'a' не уменьшается и всегда больше 0.

Comment: Если так сделать то на экране неравномерно мигает цифра 90 и всё.                                              
a = 100;
b = timeToFrames(t = time + thisComp.displayStartTime, fps = 1.0 / thisComp.frameDuration, isDuration = false) 
if (a > 0){ 
  if (b%9==0){
  a -= 10;
}
}